# 'with_indifferent_access' with a polymorphic association in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to create a record with some nested attributes and the nested attributes are in a polymorphic model; something like this:

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :address_attributes

  has_one :address, as: :location_data_source

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :address_attributes

  has_one :address, as: :location_data_source

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :street, :city

    belongs_to :location_data_source, polymorphic: true
end
```

And I'd like to create a record like this:

```
o = Office.create(:name = 'The Big Office', description = 'a really big office' :address_attributes => [:street => 'main street', :city => 'No Name City'])
```

But I get an 'with_indifferent_access' error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for...

I think I'm struggling becuase I don't really understand what the error means. Any ideas?

Comment: Try assigning a hash to address_attributes rather than an array.

Comment: Lol - thanks depa that worked great... so easy when you know how :)